# Many-to-many ICollection is still empty even though data has been inserted

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have two entities, one is `Product` and looks something like this:

```
[Key]
public int ID {get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

and the other is `Category` and looks like this:

```
[Key]
public int ID {get; set;}
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

Both objects are simplified massively here.

My insert method looks like this:

```
public static Product AddProduct(ProductDTO product)
{
    using var context = new ProjectDbContext();

    Product newProduct = Product.ConvertDTO(product);

    var contr = context.Products;
    contr.Add(newProduct);
    context.SaveChanges();

    if (product.Categories != null  && product.Categories.Count() > 0)
    {
        var list = from r in context.categories 
                   where product.Categories.Contains(r.ID) 
                   select r;
        newProduct.Categories = list.ToList();
    }

    contr.Update(newProduct);
    context.SaveChanges();

    return newProduct;
}
```

The `ProductDTO` is just an object that has the product data and a list of category ids.

The product is inserted and the data is also written into the generated connection table inside the database. However when I now try to get the inserted product, its categories are null, even though it should have three category objects.

Comment: Where did `product` come from? Why did you not add the new product to existing categories? This seems like such a bizarre way to try and link up entities. You have a `newProduct` that you want to put into existing Categories; why not just either add a category to the newProduct.Categories, or find the relevant categories and add newProduct to them?

Comment: product is a dto send by an asp.net controller. you don't need the foreach block and update block actually, I was just testing around to see if it would work. Even without it the database is filled correctly but the Icollection still stays null.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I think I found a solution. I forgot to eager load, when getting the entity:

```
contr = context.Products.Include(x => x.Categories).Where(x=> x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
```